# Keycloak with Api gateway

Tags: authentication, authorization, microservices, keycloak, api-gateway

I've did the Keycloak configuration to register/login using credentials as well as with Google OAuth. Now I would like to hide my Keycloak behind Api Gateway, so people from outside won't even know I'm using keycloak for authentication and authorization.
I imagined that my UI, which I will provide later, would simply send the requests to corresponding api gateway endpoints in order to login/register or trigger the OAuth login process.

Here however I've faced a problem, that apparently no-one follows this approach over the internet and configuring my api gateway with keycloak feels like a over-engineering.

I couldn't find any proper tutorial where people would hide keycloak functionality behind the api gateway. I've always imagined that companies like Facebook, Linkedin or even Stack Overflow follows this approach, that they have some api gateway behind which there is keycloak.

It's really hard to find any valuable information on how to login/register with credentials/OAuth via http requests to keycloak, everywhere is the approach "just use the keycloak UI!". It made me already reconsider a couple of times just writing my own auth service...

Could anyone actually explain to me if the approach of having api gateway and keycloak fully behind it makes sense? How does companies like Facebook/Linkedin/StackOverflow handles the Login/Register process with Credentials as well as OAuth? Should I write my own auth service, or write some proxy between api-gateway and keycloak?

Any suggestions on how to implement such thing would be helpful!

Thanks!